# Counting values to get to a specified column share threshold in R

Tags: r, apply

I have the following data stored in a list. I am subsequently sorting each column within df1 and df2 to find the share of the top 5 values per column:

```
set.seed(12345)
df1 = data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:500,1000,rep=TRUE)))
df2 = data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:500,1000,rep=TRUE)))
list = list(df1, df2)

do.call(cbind,lapply(list, function(x) {
x1 <- x/colSums(x)[col(x)]
sapply(x1, function(y) sum(head(sort(y, decreasing = TRUE), 5)))}))
```

How do I adapt this code to find, for each column, the count of values *sorted from largest to smallest* to get to 80% of the column total (i.e., if the top 3 values in a column make up 80.1%, then the answer would be 3 for that column)?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I think `set.seed = 12345` is not doing what you think it's doing. (See [`?set.seed`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Random.html).) For proof, try `set.seed=12345;runif(1);` twice. (Bottom line: `set.seed(12345)`.)

Comment: nymuffin, does the answer below resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Piece-wise (solution at the end):

```
col <- lst[[1]]$X1
( s80 <- 0.8*sum(col) )
# [1] 205634.4
```

I think you want to add the largest, second largest, etc up and find out how many of these (in decreasing order) are necessary to contain 80% of the sum, which is `s80`.

So first we sort:

```
head( sorted <- sort(col, decreasing=TRUE) ,n=10)
#  [1] 499 499 498 497 497 496 495 495 495 494
```

And we cumulative sum them:

```
head( cumsum(sorted) ,n=10)
#  [1]  499  998 1496 1993 2490 2986 3481 3976 4471 4965
```

And those that are gte `s80` (should be one index and all beyond it):

```
head(which( cumsum(sorted) >= s80 ))
# [1] 563 564 565 566 567 568
```

We can safely grab the first.

```
do.call(rbind,
        lapply(lst, function(l) {
          sapply(l, function(col) {
            s80 <- 0.8*sum(col)
            sorted <- sort(col, decreasing=TRUE)
            which(cumsum(sorted) >= s80)[1]
          })
        })
        )
#       X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9 X10
# [1,] 563 560 543 549 555 558 554 567 552 550
# [2,] 541 551 547 560 549 550 557 546 557 555
```